# How to compare two lists with two conditions?

Tags: python, list, for-loop

## What I am specifically trying to do

```
symbol_list = ["....firstline.\\.||hi",
               "pythonisasnake..\....",
               "||||last.\\|line\\..."]

normal_list = ["ABCDfirstlineEFGHIJhi",
               "pythonisasnakeKLMNOPQ",
               "RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD"]
```

In the `symbol_list`, I want to replace symbols with the letter in the corresponding position in `normal_list` and I want to replace the non-symbols in the list with a `*`

- The symbols will always be `.` `\` `|`

### The expected output:

```
new_list = ["ABCD*********EFGHIJ**",
            "**************KLMNOPQ",
            "RSTU****VWXY****ZABCD"]
```

**What is the solution to doing this?**

## What I tried to do

For both lists, I somehow needed to access every item in each row which seemed really complicated to do. I tried to start this with for loops:

```
for symbol_row in symbol_list:
    for symbol_item in symbol_row:
        for normal_row in normal_list:
            for normal_item in normal_row:
```

This was confusing and it seems as if it is recommended to do at most two

I then tried to check one of the conditions:

```
if symbol_item in (".","\\","|"): # because \ is an escape character
    symbol_row = symbol_row.replace(symbol_item, normal_item)
```

Then I appended this new row to `new_list` but my list ended up 10 times longer than it was before after I printed it out

```
new_list.append(symbol_row)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with a line comprehension and ternary comparison:

```
symbol_list = ["....firstline.\\.||hi",
               "pythonisasnake..\....",
               "||||last.\\|line\\..."]

normal_list = ["ABCDfirstlineEFGHIJhi",
               "pythonisasnakeKLMNOPQ",
               "RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD"]

print([''.join([n if not s.isalpha() else '*' for n,s in zip(nor, sym)])
                    for nor, sym in zip(normal_list, symbol_list)])
```

Comment: Does that produce lists instead of strings?

Comment: a string is a list. Also, @Jondiedoop you could use `not str.isalpha()` to determine if it's a symbol.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Jaba, edited it in. Incidentially, I added the "".join(), so it is actually one string

Comment: Working with lists having corresponding values, zip should be the first thing that comes to your mind. +1

Comment: @Jaba a `str` is not a `list`.

Comment: You're correct, although strings can, in most cases, be treated in similar ways. Thanks for correcting me

Answer (score 1):

This code should do what you need.

```
symbol_list = ["....firstline.\\.||hi",
               "pythonisasnake..\....",
               "||||last.\\|line\\..."]

normal_list = ["ABCDfirstlineEFGHIJhi",
               "pythonisasnakeKLMNOPQ",
               "RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD"]

letters = "AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHhIiJjKkLlMmNnOoPpQqRrSsTtUuVvWwXxYyZz"

new_list = []

for i in range(len(symbol_list)):
    new_list.append("")
    for index in range(len(symbol_list[i])):
        if letters.find(symbol_list[i][index]) != -1:
            new_list[i] += "*"
        else:
            new_list[i] += normal_list[i][index]

print(new_list)
input()
```

It finds all the instances of letters in the symbol_list and puts an asterisk in the new list

Answer (score 0):

We can write this like:

```
my_symbols = {'\\', '|', '.'}

[
  ''.join(('*', cb)[ca in my_symbols] for ca, cb in zip(linea, lineb))
  for linea, lineb in zip(symbol_list, normal_list)
]
```

here we thus first define a set of symbols (to make it easy to extend this). Next we concurrently iterate over the lines of the `symbol_list` and the `normal_list`. For each line, we then iterate over the two lines, and use `ca` (the character of the `symbol_list` line) as a selector to decide if we fill in `'*'` or `cb` for that specific character.

The output for your sample input is:

```
>>> [
...   ''.join(('*', cb)[ca in my_symbols] for ca, cb in zip(linea, lineb))
...   for linea, lineb in zip(symbol_list, normal_list)
... ]
['ABCD*********EFGHI**', '**************KLMNOPQ', 'RSTU****VWX****eZAB']
```

In your sample input there is a bit of a "misalignment" on the last line since it contains:

```
||||last.\|line\...
RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD
```

so your last line contains:

```
||||last.\|line\...
RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD
---------------------
RSTU****VWXY***eZAB
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer readability over length,

```
symbol_list = ["....firstline.\\.||hi",
               "pythonisasnake..\....",
               "||||last.\\|line\\..."]

normal_list = ["ABCDfirstlineEFGHIJhi",
               "pythonisasnakeKLMNOPQ",
               "RSTUlastVWXYlineZABCD"]



final_list = list()
for nor, sym in zip(normal_list, symbol_list):
    temp_string = ""
    for n, s in zip(nor, sym):
        if s.isalpha():
            temp_string += '*'
        else:
            temp_string += n
    final_list.append(temp_string)

print(final_list)

# output,
['ABCD*********EFGHI**', '**************KLMNOPQ', 'RSTU****VWX****eZAB']
```